# Paging in slickGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, paging, slickgrid, pager

I was able to utilize paging in slickGrid however I am new to jquery and slickGrid and can't get to move in between pages. can anyone help me with this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {var columns = [
{id:"counter", name:"#",field:"counter"},
{id:"data1", name:"Data 1",field:"data1"},
{id:"data2", name:"Data 2",field:"data2"},
{id:"data3", name:"Data 3",field:"data3"},
{id:"data4", name:"Data 4",field:"data4"}];

var options = { enableCellNavigation: false,
enableColumnReorder: false};

var FB_C_grid;
var FB_C_data;
var selectedRowIds = [];
var dataView;

$(function() {
FB_C_data = []; 
FB_C_data[0]={"id":"0",
"data1":"test1",
"data2":"test1",
"data3":"test1",
"data4":"test1,
"counter":"1"
}; 

for (var i=1; i<50000; i++) {
    var d = (FB_C_data[i] = {});enter code here

    d["id"] = "id_" + i;
    d["data1"] = "data1_" + i;
    d["data2"] = "data2_" + i;
    d["data3"] = "data3_" + i;
    d["data4"] = "data4_" + i;
                d["counter"] = i;
   }


    dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
    dataView.setItems(FB_C_data);
    dataView.setPagingOptions({pageSize:20});
    FB_C_grid= new Slick.Grid($("#FB_C_sheet"),dataView.rows, columns,options);
    var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, FB_C_grid, $("#pagerTest"));

    dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function(rows) {
 FB_C_grid.removeRows(rows);
 FB_C_grid.render();

         if (selectedRowIds.length > 0)
    {
     // since how the original data maps onto rows has changed,
     // the selected rows in the grid need to be updated
     var selRows = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < selectedRowIds.length; i++)
     {
      var idx = dataView.getRowById(selectedRowIds[i]);
      if (idx != undefined)
       selRows.push(idx);
     }

      FB_C_grid.setSelectedRows(selRows);
    }
   });

   dataView.onPagingInfoChanged.subscribe(function(pagingInfo) {
    var isLastPage = pagingInfo.pageSize*(pagingInfo.pageNum+1)-1 >= pagingInfo.totalRows;
                var enableAddRow = isLastPage || pagingInfo.pageSize==0;
                var options = FB_C_grid.getOptions();

                if (options.enableAddRow != enableAddRow)
         FB_C_grid.setOptions({enableAddRow:enableAddRow});
   });

               dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function(args) {
    FB_C_grid.updateRowCount();
                FB_C_grid.render();
   });

})

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see some of your errors as you are trying to pass a jQuery object into SlickGrid while SlickGrid already uses jQuery in the code behind. When you create your SlickGrid object, you just need to pass the name of your grid and so in your code, you have to replace this `$("#pagerTest")` without jQuery wrapper becomes this `"#pagerTest"`

I see you called it the same in 2 different locations, so replace your 2 lines with this:

```
FB_C_grid= new Slick.Grid("#FB_C_sheet",dataView.rows, columns,options);
var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, FB_C_grid, "#pagerTest");
```

Hope that helps you make it to work...